# Wordpress html в конец

Tags: php, wordpress, url

Можно ли как то добавить .html в конец ссылки только определенной страницы???

Comment: if($suite=='networ.net\index'){ $new=$suite.'html';}

Comment: Это нужно в строку записать.... Тоесть это должна быть полноценная ссылка на страницу

Comment: echo '<a href=".$new.">Ссылка</a>';  // вот это ниже

Comment: Нет! Нужно сдетлать url ссылку. Чтобы в строку браузера добавлялося

Comment: это как? что уже есть  какая ссылка от куда она приходит?

Comment: add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'noPage_slash', 66, 2 );
function noPage_slash( $string, $type ){
    global $wp_rewrite;
 
    if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes == true && $type == 'page'){
        return untrailingslashit( $string );
    }
    return $string;
}

add_action('init', 'htmlPage_permalink', -1);
function htmlPage_permalink() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
 
     if( ! strpos( $wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.html') ){
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.html';
     }
}

Comment: Этот код добавляет во все ссылки, а мне нужно только в конкретные

Comment: у тебя массив ссылок получается да?

Comment: можно из массива выделить те которые надо foreach  if($value=='1suite', or ...

Comment: Ответ из [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/244146/how-can-i-add-html-to-the-end-of-a-single-url-on-a-wordpress-website)